# DB2 Trigger not working

Tags: sql, triggers, db2

I have to write a after delete trigger on table TABLE_A which is supposed to insert record in another table TABLE_B.

Here I have to fetch 2 columns from a join on another table TABLE_C for inserting it in TABLE_B.

Below is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER SCHEMA_A.TABLE_A_TRIG 
    AFTER DELETE ON SCHEMA_A.TABLE_A
    REFERENCING  OLD AS O
    FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO SCHEMA_A.TABLE_B(GIN,COL_A,COL_B,COL_C)     
SELECT A.GIN,A.COL_A,C.COL_B,C.COL_C FROM  SCHEMA_A.TABLE_A A LEFT OUTER JOIN SCHEMA_A.TABLE_C C ON A.GIN=C.GIN WHERE A.GIN=O.GIN
```

Problem:

Not sure what is missing in this trigger as it doesn't insert any record in the TABLE_B, but deletion happens on the TABLE_A successfully.

I went though various forums but could figure out what is the issue in above trigger.

But when I execute the Insert query using select it works fine and inserts the record in TABLE_B.

Please help me in finding what is missing in this trigger. I am on IBM DB2 v 10.

Comment: The obvious conclusion is that no rows in `TABLE_A` match `O.GIN`.

Comment: No that's not the case we have records with same gin in table_a and table_c

Comment: . . You may *think* that is not the case, but it really is the obvious explanation.  How about inserting the `old` values into another table with no joins, just to test the trigger.

Comment: Yup I tried that by hardcodingly supply gin in my select inside trigger which existed in both table_a and table_c

Comment: Not hardcoded, but just something like `SELECT count(*) FROM  SCHEMA_A.TABLE_A A LEFT OUTER JOIN SCHEMA_A.TABLE_C C ON A.GIN=C.GIN WHERE A.GIN=O.GIN`.